# How to convert oracle table data into separate xml file using store procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I want to know how to convert table data into xml separate file. Whether I need to use UTL file concepts?. Below is the sample code. can any one help me to clear on this?

```
CREATE OR PROCEDURE PRC_INSDB_XML (Booking_date1 in date)
as 

begin

SELECT XMLElement("Employee", XMLForest(empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno, gender)) AS "RESULT" FROM emp where Booking_date=Booking_date1 ;

end PRC_INSDB_XML;
/
```

Answer (score 7):

You can generate XML using dbms_xmlgen.getxml() function.Find below link for details:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb12gen.htm#1025729

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml( 'select * from emp') as emp_xml 
from dual;
```

However to create an XML on your disk you need UTL package.
Eg.

```
DECLARE
      F UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
       MYCLOB CLOB;
   BEGIN
       SELECT
         DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('
           select deptno,dname,loc from emp
        ')
      INTO MYCLOB
      FROM DUAL;
      F := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(dest_path,'EMP.XML','w',32767);
      UTL_FILE.PUT(F,MYCLOB);
      UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F);
  END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I need result as a xml file in my local.

Comment: Once again thanks for your updates. I don't have privileges to create directory. If any alter way to capture xml file in folder.

Comment: If you do not have priviliges to create a directory, you should probably use the solution suggested by Andris. Your client will produce a local file.

Answer (score 3):

If you need it on your client machine then try spooling in Sql*plus

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LONG 90000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SPOOL c:\downloads\file_name.xml

select dbms_xmlgen.getxml( 'select * from emp') as emp_xml 
    from dual;

SPOOL OFF
```